# Authorized.Net Android Integration

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I was integrating Authorized.Net in my android application I followed https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/ this link of Authorized.Net but when I pasted code in my eclipse it shows me errors on imports and net.autorize.android package is not included in SDK.

`import net.authorize.android.AuthNet;
import net.authorize.android.AuthNetActivityBase;
import net.authorize.android.SimpleActivity;
import net.authorize.android.button.AuthNetButton;`